# Show only first children level of current category?

Tags: categories, children

I wish to display only first level of subcategories on current category page (if any).

I tried this code:

```
<?php
        $args=array(
            'child_of' => $cat-id,
            'hide_empty' => 0,
            'orderby' => 'name',
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'depth' => '1' //NOT WORKING

        );
        $categories=get_categories($args);
        foreach($categories as $category) {
            echo '<a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $category->name.'</a>';  }
        ?>
```

But, it shows all children, and children's children (grandchildren). I tried with "'depth' => '1'" but it is ignored.

How to show only first level of children (if exist) on category page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using get_categories() function and this function have not '**depth**' argument. Also php is not supporting `$cat-id` variable. it would be `$cat_id`.

So try this kind of code:

```
$cat_id = get_query_var('cat');
$args=array(
            'parent' => $cat_id,
            'hide_empty' => 0,
            'orderby' => 'name',
            'order' => 'ASC'
        );
```

Comment: I tried that, but now it give me just first level categories on any category/subcategory.

Comment: I managed to do this with adding '$cat_id = get_query_var('cat');'. It works now.